# How to use FreeGLUT glutMouseWheelFunc in PyOpenGL program?

Tags: python, pyopengl, freeglut

I have installed **PyOpenGL** from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for 64-bit Python 3.x and Windows 7. I am able to write and execute a PyOpenGL program that uses **glutMouseFunc** to listen to mouse button clicks:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

# Imagine the typical glut init functions here ...
glutMouseFunc( mouse )
```

Now, I want to read the **scroll wheel** of the mouse too. I have done this before in C++ using FreeGLUT, which exposes a **glutMouseWheelFunc**. I checked and I can see **freeglut32.vc9.dll** and **freeglut64.vc9.dll** in `C:\Program Files\Python32\Lib\site-packages\OpenGL\DLLS`.

I changed the above code to:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

# Imagine the typical glut init functions here ...
glutMouseFunc( mouse )
glutMouseWheelFunc( mouseWheel )
```

This fails with this error:

```
  File "c:\Program Files\Python32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 139, in __call__
    self.wrappedOperation( cCallback, *args )
  File "c:\Program Files\Python32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 107, in failFunction
    typeName, 'glut%sFunc'%(typeName),
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Undefined GLUT callback function MouseWheel, check for bool(glutMouseWheelFunc) before calling
```

So, **how do I use FreeGLUT calls in PyOpenGL**? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyOpenGL loads the GLUT dll by default. To use freeglut instead, rename or delete the glut64.vc9.dll file in the OpenGL/DLLs directory and make sure no such file exists elsewhere in the Windows DLL search path. Works for me.