# Using glutMouseWheelFunc from FreeGLUT in PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, glut, freeglut, pyopengl

If I run this code

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut import *

def on_wheel(wheel, direction, x, y):
    print(wheel, direction, x, y)

glutInit()
glutInitWindowSize(100, 100)
glutCreateWindow("glutMouseWheelFunc test")
glutMouseWheelFunc( on_wheel ) # Error here
glutMainLoop()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 28, in <module>
    glutMouseWheelFunc( on_wheel )
  File ".../OpenGL/GLUT/special.py", line 148, in __call__
    self.wrappedOperation( cCallback, *args )
  File ".../OpenGL/GLUT/special.py", line 116, in failFunction
    typeName, 'glut%sFunc'%(typeName),
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Undefined GLUT callback function MouseWheel,
check for bool(glutMouseWheelFunc) before calling
```

Here's the solution for Windows:

[How to use FreeGLUT glutMouseWheelFunc in PyOpenGL program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359407/how-to-use-freeglut-glutmousewheelfunc-in-pyopengl-program)

But how can I call **`glutMouseWheelFunc()`** in pyopengl on Mac or linux?

Or better: is there a portable solution?

Answer (score 1):

The function **glutMouseFunc()** should be defined before **glutMouseWheelFunc()** the example now works from your code with the following on Linux:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut import *

def mouse(button, state, x, y):
    print(button, state, x, y)

def on_wheel(wheel, direction, x, y):
    print(wheel, direction, x, y)

glutInit()
glutInitWindowSize(100, 100)
glutCreateWindow("glutMouseWheelFunc test")
glutMouseFunc( mouse )
glutMouseWheelFunc( on_wheel )
glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that gives **OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Undefined GLUT callback function MouseWheel, check for bool(glutMouseWheelFunc) before calling** so I suppose it's not supported